# key down listner event not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a 'keydown' event on javascript for navigating table using arrow keys:

my code as follows:

```
document.onkeydown= function() { keyDown();};
```

The implementation code as follows:

```
function keyDown(e){
    var evt=(e)?e:(window.event)?window.event:null;
    var key = evt.keyCode || evt.which;

    if(key==38 || key==40){
     alert("working");
      }

}
```

How can I make it works on all browsers? What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `event` variable that the system passes in to your function or use the standardised `addEventListener` method:

```
// Passing the event
document.onkeydown = function(e) { keyDown(e); };
// Using event listeners
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);
```

Then you should rely on the `event` passed - do not use `window.event` - if the `event` is *not* passed to your function you have bigger issues to worry about than finding the event.

```
function keyDown(e){
    if(e.which == 38 || e.which == 40){
       alert("working");
    }
}
```

I would learn more about the `addEventListener` method as assigning functions to the documents own `onEvent` attributes is not advised. What if you want to change this later? What if you want to add some code some of the time? Event Listeners are great for that and they don't modify the default behaviour here. You can add and remove these on the fly, making it much more versatile. Have a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener